# Installing Blackfire prob issue

Tags: laravel-5, homestead, blackfire

Having some issue trying to get Blackfire.io set up on my homestead box.

Followed the installation guide a couple of times now, and no having no errors.

When I try to use the chrome companion I get the follow error ...

> Are you authorized to profile this page? Probe not found, invalid signature

Also when I try to check out what version of the prob I am using via **php --ri blackfire** I get the follow message despite installing it as per the guide

> Extension 'blackfire' not present.

Any ideas!?

Many thanks!

Comment: FWIW, I'm very new to Blackfire on Linux. My impression is that if `php --ri blackfire` returns an error, it's either not installed or it's not in your path. Also try `php -i | grep blackfire`. If that shows nothing, it seems like Blackfire isn't installed.

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out Dean?

Comment: Can you please share if you have done with that ?

Comment: Hi, Sorry I never got it working and time ran out so I had to unfortunately continue without solving.

Answer (score 3):

in my case (i'm using  vagrant) this helped:

in  file

```
/etc/php5/mods-available/blackfire.ini
```

add

```
extension=blackfire.so
```

Comment: I am using windows, so would blackfire.so works on it??

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had to check the black-fire agent status, and when I found out it was not active I restart it and it works fine.

To check the status:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/blackfire-agent status
```

To restart :

```
sudo /etc/init.d/blackfire-agent restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when installing blackfire probe as mentionned in the official documentation. And here is how i solved it.

Since I am using MAMP's php in my terminal i installed the PHP Probe manually instead of installing it with homebrew.

In fact in the first place i tried to instal it with homebrew and that's how i get the same error as you :

When i run this command :

`php --ri blackfire`

I get :

> Extension 'blackfire' not present.

To fix this issue i had to install the probe manually by following theses steps:

- download the probe library as mentionoed in the blackfire doc

You should have a file like this : blackfire-php-**********.so

- rename it to: blackfire.so
- execute this command in your terminal, it should tell you where you can put the downloaded file:

`php -i | grep 'extension_dir'`

- move the blackfire.so file to the mentionned directory.
- Close all your terminal windows and restart mamp
- Execute `php -m` in your terminal; if you can see blackfire in the list that means that your extension is working correctly.